# How can I remove C-a as a byobu tmux prefix?

Tags: byobu, tmux

I figured out how to add

```
set -g prefix ^B
```

to .byobu/profile.tmux

I typed the same command at the tmux : line and indeed ^B is now my prefix character, but ^A is also still my prefix character. I'd like to unbind it. I've tried unbind ^A at the : prompt. I've tried unbind-key ^A and unbind C-a and unbind-key C-a and none of them work.

How can I unbind ^A without restarting my tmux session?

Answer (score 5):

Easy answer which took me 1 day to find:  run byobu-ctrl-a

```
$ byobu-ctrl-a
```

It asks what ctrl-a should do and the change is immediate.

I found I could also pass argument to it, such as "emacs" meaning, don't let tmux use it.

```
$ byobu-ctrl-a emacs
```

It turns out all this script does is ask the currently running tmux to source its config again from beginning. I could have done this manually by ^B:source-file /usr/share/byobu/profiles/tmuxrx

That system byobu file sources my local user config for byobu-tmux, so my key change took effect.

Comment: This helped me. Thanks.
In my situation i had tmux use C-s as the prefix but thanks to this byobu was also using C-a as the prefix.

Answer (score 0):

1. Launch `byobu-config` directly or with <kbd>F9</kbd> shortcut

   [image: byobu config screenshot]
2. Select your character

   [image: escape squence]